# Strange flickering after manipulating html with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck with a problem and I cannot figure out what the cause is, I have created a small js script that modifies a table element, but every time it does I see flickering of the elements, I checked the HTML elements and there is no white space or whatsoever.

Short video: https://i.imgur.com/86RODJL.mp4

Is it possible an css property that causes this behavior ?

Tried to troubleshoot by inspecting the html elements for white space or similar.

JS function:

```
function correctOrderQtyMinus(element) {
var elementTR = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
var totalExBTW = document.getElementById('totalExBTW');
var totalBtw = document.getElementById('totalBtw');
var btwAmount = document.getElementById('btwAmount');
if(document.getElementById('checkoutForm')) {
if(element.parentNode.querySelector('#productQty').value > 1) {
  var newAmount =+ parseFloat(elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceTotalBtw').innerText) - parseFloat(elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceWithBtw').innerText);
 elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceTotalBtw').innerText =+ newAmount.toFixed(2);
 totalExBTW.innerText =+  (parseFloat(totalExBTW.innerText)- parseFloat(elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceExBtw').innerText)).toFixed(2);
 totalBtw.innerText =+  (parseFloat(totalBtw.innerText) - parseFloat(elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceWithBtw').innerText)).toFixed(2);
 btwAmount.innerText = parseFloat(totalBtw.innerText - totalExBTW.innerText).toFixed(2);
 totalBtw.innerText = parseFloat(totalBtw.innerText).toFixed(2);
 totalExBTW.innerText = parseFloat(totalExBTW.innerText).toFixed(2);
 elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceTotalBtw').innerText  =  parseFloat(elementTR.querySelector('#productPriceTotalBtw').innerText).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        console.log('Cannot go less than 1');
    }
     
}  
 
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: We can't debug a video. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: this is caused by your grid layout. The last column is only as wide as the content and as such increases or decreases with the price